# WHERE condition on subqueried count value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables.

```
table deals
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | location_id |
+----+------+-------------+

table deals_user_actions
+---------+---------+
| deal_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+

table locations
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | longitude | latitude |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

My original working query was:

```
SELECT d.id, d.title
FROM deals d
JOIN locations l ON l.id = d.location_id
WHERE ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MAKEPOINT(l.longitude, l.latitude), ST_MAKEPOINT(18, 59), 'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]') < 50
```

But I need to select deals that only have a certain amount of user actions, like this:

```
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.title,
    COUNT(dua.deal_id) AS numUserActions
FROM deals d
JOIN locations l ON l.id = d.location_id
JOIN deals_user_actions dua ON dua.deal_id = d.id
WHERE 
    ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MAKEPOINT(l.longitude, l.latitude), ST_MAKEPOINT(18, 59), 'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]') < 50
    AND numUserActions == 10
```

But here it complains about not having the d.id, l.longitude and l.latitude columns in the GROUP BY clause. But when I add them, only one result is returned in the query.

So how would you recommended changing the query to give a result conditioned on a COUNTed JOINed table?

Comment: or you can remove `d.id` from `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to join `deals_user_actions`. Simply use a subselect in your WHERE clause to count:

```
SELECT d.id, d.title
FROM deals d
JOIN locations l ON l.id = d.location_id
WHERE ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MAKEPOINT(l.longitude, l.latitude),
                           ST_MAKEPOINT(18, 59), 
                           'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]') < 50
AND (select count(*) from deals_user_actions dua where dua.deal_id = d.id) = 10
```

**UPDATE 1:** If you want to show the number of actions, then join the aggregated data instead:

```
SELECT d.id, d.title, dua.actions
FROM deals d
JOIN locations l ON l.id = d.location_id
JOIN
(
  select deal_id, count(*) as actions
  from deals_user_actions
  group by deal_id
  having actions = 10
) dua ON dua.deal_id = d.id
WHERE ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MAKEPOINT(l.longitude, l.latitude),
                           ST_MAKEPOINT(18, 59), 
                           'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]') < 50
```

**UPDATE 2:**  For completeness sake, I show you your original query only slightly modified with GROUP BY and HAVING. You see, when asking for an aggregate result (`COUNT(*)` here), you cannot do so in WHERE which works on the tables' records, but in HAVING which works on the aggregated groups.

However, it's a good habit to join aggregates as I have shown above, and not join the tables first and then aggregate as shown below. (With the latter you easily get issues when having to work with aggregates from several tables.)

```
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.title,
    COUNT(dua.deal_id) AS numUserActions
FROM deals d
JOIN locations l ON l.id = d.location_id
JOIN deals_user_actions dua ON dua.deal_id = d.id
WHERE ST_Distance_Spheroid(ST_MAKEPOINT(l.longitude, l.latitude),
                           ST_MAKEPOINT(18, 59), 
                           'SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563]') < 50
GROUP BY d.id, d.title
HAVING numUserActions = 10
```

Comment: Thats clever! :) But what if I want to have the value returned as well in the result?

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and explanation. Works great!

Comment: Oh, one problem though. In your UPDATE1 example, I can't specify in the WHERE clause that I only want deals with 10 user actions (WHERE COALESCE(dua.actions, 0) = 10). It says "column dua.actions does not exist". I tried to alias the field as well but with no success.

Comment: That is strange. `dua.actions` is in the SELECT list, so it is accessable. I see no reason, why it can't be used in the WHERE clause. I've updated my answer in order to show the complete query. Sorry I forgot about that part. You see I use HAVING inside the subquery to apply this restriction as soon as possible, but you could just as well add `AND dua.actions = 10` to the ON clause or the main query's WHERE clause.

Comment: Ah, the problem was that when I used the alias in the WHERE clause. It actually worked if I only used dua.actions. Is there some performance gain when using HAVING inside the JOIN for when using dua.actions in the WHERE clause in the outer query?

Comment: I guess no. But I would always apply restrictions as soon as possible in order to avoid large intermediate results. The first place would hence be the HAVING clause inside, then the ON clause outside, then the WHERE clause outside. Probably it doesn't really make a difference and the DBMS would generate the same execution plan for all these options. So there would probably be no performance penalties when putting the criteria in a "later" place, but why risk it?